# Consulta para tener solo los nombres de registros

Tags: mysql

Necesito una consulta que me muestre de una tabla **nombre** en la cual están juntos apellidos y nombres separados por una coma ejemplo :

**Martinez Nutero, Juan Alberto**

y necesito que sólo me muestre el valor a partir de la coma. Probé con esta consulta pero no me funciona. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

```
 select right(nombre,select locate(',',nombre) from asd_personas) from asd_personas
```

Comment: ¿El nombre y los apellidos están en la columna `nombre`? si es así, no me parece que se pueda establecer la diferencia entre nombres y apellidos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para lo que necesitas puede servirte SUBSTRING_INDEX, prueba asi:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(nombre, ',', 1) as nombre,SUBSTRING_INDEX(nombre, ',', -1) as apellido FROM asd_personas
```